# Background update issue on iOS app

Tags: ios, multithreading

I'm trying to make an "auto-update" process to make the user stay updated every X minutes while the app's awake. What I'm doing it's a background call every X minutes that asks the server if there are updates to make or not.

The thing is that when I make a call and the server returns YES, I've got to to update two things: my local DB and also the user interface (cause there might be changes on the interface too).

What I've got now is a thread problem. If I don't make any drawing while the app's updating I've got no issue, but when I do the app crashes.

Any ideas how could I control that threading issue?

Comment: Can you show some code?  Specifically an example of what you are doing when 'the server returns YES' would be helpful.  Also include what thread that code is called on.

Comment: Ok, when the server returns YES this is what I do. I call a background method that makes these things:
1) Clear the DB
2) Update the DB
3) Save the new json 
4) Update the views

When I tried to debug this, the problem came when trying to do 2).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using CoreData for your database.  You need to make sure that any updates you make to the managed object context occur on the thread on which that context was created (typically the main thread).

You also need to make sure that any updates you make to the user interface also occur on the **main** thread.

Comment: Yes, you assumed right. My main problem was clearing everything and then updating everything. After arranging that, I was making all the updates on background threads and that made me have some trouble too that were solved by making that updates on the main thread. Thank you for the advices!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try running the code on a background thread. one easy way to do this is preformSelectorOnBackgroundThread method...